# How do we set up parallel running of tests using jenkins and nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, jenkins

I have a nodejs app. How do I set up jenkins so that it runs my tests in parallel? I'm using grunt test (grunt) to run my tests. I'm using mocha, chai, and sinon

Comment: which testing framework? JasminE?!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know you have got the answer already or not, if not please check it.

[Jenkins CI integrate with NodeJS and Github problems in configuring build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315340/jenkins-ci-integrate-with-nodejs-and-github-problems-in-configuring-build/35333011#35333011)

I have recently posted there my setup of jenkins with nodejs and parallel tests running with Jasmine-node and Frisby

you need to add grunt task to add test spec folder and files into build.
and configure testing commands into SSH Publisher in project configuration page 
Exec Commands.

```
    cd projectname 
    rm -rf public server package.json
    tar -xvf projectname.tgz 
    ls
    npm install --production
    export NODE_ENV=production 
    forever restartall
    jasmine-node spec/api/frisbyapi_spec.js 
    jasmine-node spec/maintest.js
    rm -rf projectname.tgz
```