# Jenkins CI integrate with NodeJS and Github problems in configuring build

Tags: nginx, github, jenkins, junit, continuous-integration

We have build our first Nodejs app and I want to integrate Jenkins as continuous integration we are running node server behind Nginx as proxy and source control in Gitlab. I need example configurations or steps. 
I am looking here any doc or wiki link or if you can point me into right direction it will be helpful
I have CentOS server and managed to install and configure Jenkins but not getting the proper way to connect my Gitlab server. I need to run npm commands after each build. If any one already has done that please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: stackoverflow.com is not a site to post jobs. You would be better off hunting for a freelancer for this.

Comment: I will edit my question and make it more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is still vague but I will try to provide you here how I had done Jenkins NodeJs with Gitlab integration. I have CentOS 6 and tested.

## Steps

Open Java should be installed prior.

- sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat-stable/jenkins.repo
- sudo rpm --import https://jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins-ci.org.key
- sudo yum install jenkins
- sudo service jenkins start

Login as jenkins

- sudo -s -H -u jenkins

Now generate the ssh key in the folder /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh and copy that key to gitlab

- ssh-keygen
- Install Gitlab Hook Plugin and GitLab Plugin in jenkins.

As  you will create a project by accessing your jenkins in browser 
After creating the project go to configure (left side menu) project page
There lots of options are self explanatory - setup Git repo url
and setup mail git browser url.

- Create a new item in jenkins and add the git repo url and in build triggers 
  select Build when a change is pushed to GitLab. GitLab CI Service URL:

Build Triggers
 check the option

- Build when a change is pushed to GitLab
- Paste that url in your gitlab repo's webhooks in settings.

## This is to run npm commands after build

There is one section SSH Publisher

In exec commands section (I have put my example you can write your commands)

```
    cd project_dir
    rm -rf public server package.json
    tar -xvf projectname.tgz 
    ls
    npm install --production
    export NODE_ENV=production 
    forever restartall
    jasmine-node spec/api/frisbyapi_spec.js 
    rm -rf projectname.tgz
```

I have written most the steps that I took to setup jenkins nodejs and gitlab.
I might have forgot any step. If you face any error please post that as well.

Comment: I saw one plugin for NodeJS Jenkins    https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin     Do I need to configure that also?

Comment: If you have the requirement to install NodeJS in each build on target server then you need this plugin. I have assumed that you already have installed the NodeJS and you only need to run the build for code of projects.

Comment: Do I need to create Jenkins SSH key separately ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212304/authenticate-jenkins-ci-for-github-private-repository?rq=1                   Please look into comments of this question, it is well defined the process for generating the SSH key and locations.